# MATLAB - extracting rows of a matrix

Tags: matlab, indexing

`a = [1 2; 3 4; 5 6]` I want to extract the first and third row of `a`, so I have `x = [1; 3]` (indices of rows).

`a(x)` doesn't work.

Comment: If you keep having questions on these types of matrix manipulations, I recommend you check out the MATLAB help, or any of the many free tutorials online. If you go for the MATLAB help files, it will be a few hours that are *definitely* worth the investment.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Like this: `a([1,3],:)`

The comma separates the dimensions, `:` means "entire range", and square brackets make a list.

Answer (score 19):

In MATLAB if one parameter is given when indexing, it is so-called linear indexing. For example if you have 4x3 matrix, the linear indices of the elements look like this, they are growing by the columns:

```
1   5   9
2   6  10
3   7  11
4   8  12
```

Because you passed the [1 3] vector as a parameter, the 1st and 3rd elements were selected only.

When selecting whole columns or rows, the following format shall be used:

```
A(:, [list of columns])  % for whole columns
A([list of rows], :)     % for whole rows
```

General form of 2d matrix indexing:

```
A([list of rows], [list of columns])
```

The result is the elements in the intersection of the indexed rows and columns. Results will be the elements marked by X:

```
A([2 4], [3 4 5 7])

. . C C C . C
R R X X X R X
. . C C C . C
R R X X X R X
```

Reference and some similar examples: [tutorial on MATLAB matrix indexing](http://matlabtricks.com/post-23/tutorial-on-matrix-indexing-in-matlab).

Comment: This is much more informative than the accepted answer.  In addition, the mechanics of indexing into each dimension with vectors is not well-known with many MATLAB users.  +1.

Answer (score 1):

`x = a([1 3])` behaves like this:

```
temp = a(:)     % convert matrix 'a' into a column wise vector
x = temp([1 3]) % get the 1st and 3rd elements of 'a'
```

Comment: This doesn't completely answer the question. The OP wants all columns indexed by rows 1 and 3, not the individual elements. -1.

Answer (score 0):

you could write a loop to iterate across the rows of the matrix:

```
for i = [1,3]
    a(i,:)
end
```

Answer (score -1):

type this: `a([1 3],[1 2])`
the output is

```
ans =
     1     2
     5     6
```

Comment: This would only work if the matrix had two columns.  What if your matrix has more than 2 columns? I didn't give you a downvote though, but your answer doesn't generalize to a matrix with arbitrary dimensions, which is probably more useful.  In addition, this question has already been answered and your answer doesn't add anything more meaningful to the already established answers.  Also, with your above syntax, I found this answer in this same post more informative: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19731104/3250829 - They're actually explaining what vectors indexing into each dimension do.