# Matlab matrix indexing from 2 Arrays (X,Y)

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing

I have X and Y positions for a large array and I would like to use them to define what the contents of that position. I could run a for loop to define the positions but I think there would be a faster method. I tried to use the array position define function.

```
x = [6,2,3]
y = [1,2,3]

c = [1,1,1,2,2,3;...
     1,1,1,2,2,5;...
     2,2,1,4,2,3;...
     1,1,4,3,2,3;...
     1,2,3,4,5,3;...
     1,2,3,5,4,2];
```

When I type the equation above it results in the answer below

```
c(y,x)
ans =
 1     2     3
 1     1     1
 2     2     1
```

What I'm looking for are the 1:1 positions from the arrays.

```
c(y(1),x(1))
c(y(2),x(2))
c(y(3),x(3))
```

Is there any way to limit the arrays to a linear sequence? my only guess right now is to reshape the arrays into a cell matrix containing the individual a and b and then perform a cellfun. but I think I'm making it to complicated.

Comment: use `x` and `y` as linear indexing, by the length of columns- `c(size(c,1)*(x-1)+y)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to convert the locations into linear indices first, then you can grab the correct elements in the desired linear sequence.  You can use [`sub2ind`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) to help you do that:

```
ind = sub2ind(size(c), y, x); % Get linear indices
v = c(ind); % Get the elements
```

Doing this thus gives:

```
>> v = c(ind)

v =

     3     1     1
```

You can verify for yourself that each pair of `(y,x)` gives you the right element you're looking for.  For example, when `y = 1` and `x = 6`, the element retrieved is 3 and so on.

Comment: @Hojo.Timberwolf As further reading, this is the reason why your result is a matrix rather than a linear sequence: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19731104/3250829.  When you specify arrays for both the rows and columns of a matrix, it finds the rows and columns that intersect and returns a subset of that matrix.  Check out the post for further details.  With the post, this is why you need to convert each pair of row and column coordinates into a single linear index.  That way, you'll be able to extract individual elements rather than a subset of the matrix.